# WAMPServer wont start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing

Tags: windows, wampserver

I try to install wampserver3.0.6_x64 and I get the following message

> the program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer

I have installed all the things

I read in StackOverflow that I need to install Universal C Runtime, but I can't install this.

I'd love to know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows The need for this Runtime Library is clearly stated in the INSTALL DIALOGS. Where you would also have found a link to the downloadable installation

Comment: I don't understand, what I need to download?

Comment: Click the link and download and install the runtime that matches your Operating system

Comment: When I try to install, the popup "the update is not applicable to your computer" appear and I can't install this

Comment: What OS and version of OS are you running

Comment: windows 7 ultimate 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried the repair option

Comment: I don't have repair option, I have only OK button and when I click it, the popup closed

Comment: Nobody know how can I fix the problem with the update is not applicable to your computer?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like you have quite a bit of installing to do

Comment: No problem, just tell me what to install

Comment: See my answer its all in there including links to the MS download site

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:

**Simplest Solution**

Download a full set of MSVC runtimes from the WAMPServer alternate repo [which can be found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Look at the bottom of the page, there is a download called `All Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (x86) (32bits)` or `All Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)`

This will download a ZIP file containing all the possible required MSVC Runtime library installers. UnZip the file and run all the installers it exposes, in a logical order from lowest version to highest, one at a time.

---

*I notice from your pictures that you have not installed any of the prerequisite MSVC Runtime libraries* ***mentioned in the WAMPServer install process***. *So you will need to read this carefully and make sure your OS is fully capable of running any version of APache/MYSQL & PHP that can be installed with WAMPServer.*

#### Before running a WAMPServer install, you must read these prerequisites:

**BEFORE** proceeding with an installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that you have current versions of all these Microsoft C/C++ Runtime Libraries, if you do not check and install any missing libraries before you install Wampserver it will not install correctly and will not run correctly!

If you installed WAMPServer without paying attention to the install Dialog specifying these pre-requisites **your installation will be faulty** and you will need to remove Wampserver **BEFORE installing any missing Runtime Libraries.** and then re-install WAMPServer when all runtimes are installed.

Make sure your system has "up to date" versions of ALL these redistributable packages:-

- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2008 (VC9),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2010 (VC10),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2012 (VC11),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2013 (VC13),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2015 (VC14),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2017 (VC15)

#### BIG NOTE:

If you are running a 64bit Windows, it is recommended to install both the 32bit and 64bit versions of these runtime libraries. Remember Windows 64bit can run 32bit code and also it is possible to install either a 32bit or 64 bit WAMPServer on a 64bit Windows OS.

If you are running Window pre windows 10, and you are running a component that uses Apache/Mysql/PHP compiled with MSVC 2015(VC14) you will also need to install the `Universal C Runtime` This can be download via the standard Windows Update according to [this document on the microsoft site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3067639)

---- Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows

Links to all these redistributables can be found later in this post to assist you in finding and installing them.

#### Suggestion:

Please download each one individually and then complete it's install **before** downloading the next. The filenames of the downloaded installers are almost always the same regardless of version, it is easy to get confused and miss one out.
Check in `Control Panel -> Programs and Features` that they are all installed before proceeding to install WAMPServer.

#### Visual C++ Packages

The following packages (VC9, VC10, VC11) are required for Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3 even if you use only Apache and PHP versions VC11.
VC14 is required for Apache version 2.4.17 (or greater) and for PHP 7.

Where to find and download the MSVC Redistributable packages:

**VC9 Redistributable**
For Windows 2000 Service Pack 4; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP, W7, W8

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) (32 bits)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) (64bits)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)

**VC10 Redistributable**

For Windows 7; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Server 2008 R2; Windows Vista; Windows XP

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**VC11 Redistributable**
*Note: VC11 or higher is **not supported** by Windows XP*

Windows 7 Service Pack 1; Windows 8; Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1; Windows Server 2012; Windows Vista Service Pack 2
The **two files** `VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe` to be download are on the same page:

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (x86 and x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

**VC13 Redistributable**
Windows 7 Service Pack 1; Windows 8; Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1; Windows Server 2012; Windows Vista Service Pack 2
The **two files** `VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe` to be download are on the same page:

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

**VC14 Redistributable (Required for Apache 2.4.17 and PHP 7)**

Windows 10, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2
The **two files** `vcredist_x86.exe et vcredist_x64.exe` to be download are on the same page:

**VC15 Redistribuable (Required for Apache 2.4.26)**

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2017 x86](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746571)

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2017 x64](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572)

> VC2017 (VC15) is backward compatible to VC2015 (VC14). That means, a VC14 module can be used inside a VC15 binary. Because this compatibility the version number of the Redistributable is 14.1x.xx and after you install the Redistributable VC2017, VC2015 is removed but you can still use VC14.

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840)

**Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows**
Windows 10, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2
Follow the links on this page for your specific environment

[Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2999226)

> Note: If you installed WAMPServer before installing ALL these required runtimes, it is best to uninstall WAMPServer and then once all the runtimes are installed, reinstall WAMPServer

**Simplest Solution**
Download a full set of MSVC runtimes from the WAMPServer alternate repo [which can be found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Look at the bottom of the page, there is a download called `All Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (x86) (32bits)` or `All Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)`

This will download a ZIP file containing all the possible required MSVC Runtime libraries. UnZip the file and run all the installers it exposes, in a logical order from lowest version to highest, one at a time.

Comment: Thank you, The reason why I could not update Universal C Runtime is I have windows 7 ultimate. so I update to Windows 7 Service Pack 1 and then I managed to install Universal C Runtime and I also managed to install wampserver3.0.6_x64

Comment: Great, there is also an addon for V3.0.8. This would allow you to add MariaDB if you ever need it

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted the answer. Thanks for detail explanation!

Comment: I tried too many times but _Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows_ did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, my customer has win7 and never updated. Took long time to run. Be careful people, you need SP1 on windows7 to install necessary vc packages