# WAMP Navigator Config Issue

Tags: wamp, default-browser

I have recently upgraded my version of WAMP64 (Win10) to the latest available (Apache 2.4.23, PHP 7.0.10, Mysql 5.7.14).

All is working ok except when I click to open localhost or phpmyadmin from the menu I get an error:

"Could not execute menu item, exception - access is denied"

NOTE - this is not an error with the PORT I am listening to, WAMP otherwise works perfectly if I open Chrome manually http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ works,  just when the links are clicked from the WAMP system tray the exception is thrown when trying to open the assigned default browser

In my wamp conf file I have:

navigator ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

- I tried forward and back slashes
- I re-start the server each time I make any config changes
- I've tried setting Edge in the navigator path but I get the same error

So the problem looks to be with WAMP, possibly a bug?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348778/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-fro/42370291#42370291 Windows 10 does not come with all the older MSVC runtimes pre-installed, Some of these are needed by WAMPServer, specifically wampmanager

Comment: @RiggsFolly the link you provided is to fix WAMP not starting. As I stated in my question WAMP starts and works, only the links to open the assigned browser do not work. I have the Visual C++ dependencies installed

Comment: There are many symptoms when you do not have all the MSVC runtimes installed. Please make sure ALL the MSVC runtimes in that post are installed on your system. And if you are using 64bit Windows, you will need **BOTH the 32bit and 64bit MSVC runtimes installed**. Specifically wampmanager.exe is still a 32bit app

Comment: Note: There is a dialog as part of the install that tells you all this. The WAMPServer forum also specifies this in [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Comment: It may also be necessary to uninstall WAMPServer and then Reinstall it ___after you have ensured you have all these Runtime DLL's installed___ for them to be correctly recognised by WAMPServer, and for the WAMPServer install to function properly and completely.

Comment: When I first installed this verison of Wamp64 the brwoser was opening, I had to do a re-install and since then the feature has stopped working. I'm really not sure that my issue is missing MSVC runtimes, unless by uninstalling it has removed an MSVC?

Comment: No that wont have happened. Ignore my suggestion as you like. No skin off my nose

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem was resolved after a reboot suggesting that the MSVC runtimes were installed as required