# The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: php, apache, dll, xampp, crt

When I open Xampp and give start in Apache, it is throwing the error:

> The program cant start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

The screenshot for reference:

[image]

I have tried two solutions from the other answers:

First:

I tried "Check for updates" and done installing all the updates and restarted the machine but there is no improvement still the same issue.

Second:

I have downloaded "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)" (mine is 64 bit), then i installed it, it shows setup is successful.
But my issue still remains the same.

Comment: Sorry and thanks, Image was updated..

Answer (score 1):

**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll** Is the Universal C Runtime in Windows

Windows 10, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2 all require the `Universal C Runtime`

Follow the links on this page for your specific environment to download and install it

[Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2999226)

Comment: Mine is windows 8.1 and i tried with ```windows 8.1``` but it is showing error ```it is not applicable to your computer```

Comment: Then make sure you have all the other runtimes. You may also need the 32bit versions as I think XAMPP is still 32bit only

Comment: I have updated my question, now it shows setup is successful but the error message as like in image still continues..

Comment: So did the Universal Runtime also get installed?

Comment: XAMPP is still 32bit software, unless you are sure you downloaded a 64bit version. So all these runtimes must ALSO be installed as 32bit versions.

Comment: I think these runtimes are available only in 64 bit and there is no 32 bit i have found..

Comment: The MSVC runtimes are all available as 32bit and/or 64bit. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348778/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-fro/42370291#42370291) for links to all runtimes in both 32 and 64 bit